# How to group rows in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid, kendo-react-ui

I was able to do the following using `kendo-ui-recat-wrapper` to get a grouped Grid :

```
let dataSource = {   
  data: data,   
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: 'id',
      expanded: true
    }   
  },   
  group: [
    {
      field: 'title', // GroupBy goes on this field
      dir: 'asc'
    }   ] }
```

And Then I can pass this to the `dataSource` props of `Grid`.

I updated to `kendo-react-grid` it seems more coherent to use in a `ReactJs` project than the `jquery` wrapper.

But I didn't find how to get the same result ? There is no mention to the group option. Even here in `DataState` ([link here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/api/DataState/#toc-group)) I didn't get how to use it ?!

**EDIT : The option is not ready yet (Kendo ui React [roadmap](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/roadmap/))**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, the [native Kendo React Grid](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/) supports [grouping](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/grouping/). The syntax is different than as per the jquery wrapper (i.e. there is no dataSource prop) but I believe this is expected. Here is a simplified version of the official [grouping](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/grouping/) example:

```
import { Grid, GridColumn as Column } from '@progress/kendo-react-grid';
import { groupBy } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import products from './products.json';

class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid
                groupable={true}
                group={[ { field: 'UnitsInStock' } ]}
                data={groupBy(products, [ { field: 'UnitsInStock' } ])}
            >
                <Column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="50px" />
                <Column field="ProductName" title="Product Name" />
                <Column field="UnitsInStock" title="Units In Stock" />
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```